# Windows C++ crypto API: how to disable pin code UI for smart card

Tags: c++, windows, security, cryptography, hardware

I have the following C++ code (based on Microsoft API examples), it uses message signing and encryption API to produce PKCS#7 message.

There is a hardware token with certificate inserted (Yubikey) which requires a PIN code for the signing operation.

I want to disable the standard Windows pin popup and provide my own, so there is a call to `CryptSetProvParam` with a pin code.

The issue is that this call has no effect: I am still prompted with pin code.

If I add `CertSetCertificateContextProperty` call afterwards and set the key provider handle then nothing works anymore, for example `CryptMsgCalculateEncodedLength` returns 0x80090027.

If I comment out `CertSetCertificateContextProperty` then all operations are working but the pin code popup is still shown.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wincrypt.h>
#define MY_ENCODING_TYPE  (PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING)
void MyHandleError(char* s);

void main(void)
{
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Copyright (C) Microsoft.  All rights reserved.
    // Declare and initialize variables.

    BYTE* pbContent = (BYTE*)"Security is our only business.";
    // a byte pointer
    DWORD cbContent = strlen((char*)pbContent) + 1;
    // the size of the message
    HCERTSTORE hStoreHandle;
    HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv;
    PCCERT_CONTEXT pSignerCert;         // signer's certificate
    PCCERT_CONTEXT pRecipCert;          // receiver's certificate
    LPWSTR pswzRecipientName = L"myrecipient";
    LPWSTR pswzCertSubject = L"mysubject";
    PCERT_INFO RecipCertArray[1];
    DWORD ContentEncryptAlgSize;
    CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER ContentEncryptAlgorithm;
    CMSG_ENVELOPED_ENCODE_INFO EnvelopedEncodeInfo;
    DWORD cbEncodedBlob;
    BYTE* pbEncodedBlob;
    DWORD cbSignedBlob;
    BYTE* pbSignedBlob;
    HCRYPTMSG hMsg;
    DWORD HashAlgSize;
    CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER HashAlgorithm;
    CMSG_SIGNER_ENCODE_INFO SignerEncodeInfo;
    CERT_BLOB SignerCertBlob;
    CERT_BLOB SignerCertBlobArray[1];
    CMSG_SIGNER_ENCODE_INFO SignerEncodeInfoArray[1];
    CMSG_SIGNED_ENCODE_INFO SignedMsgEncodeInfo;
    DWORD dwKeySpec = 0;
    HCRYPTPROV rsaCryptProv = NULL;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Begin processing. Display the original message.

    printf("The original message => %s\n", pbContent);

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Acquire a cryptographic provider.

    if (CryptAcquireContext(
        &hCryptProv,      // address for handle to be returned
        NULL,             // use the current user's logon name
        NULL,             // use the default provider
        PROV_RSA_FULL,    // provider type
        0))               // zero allows access to private keys
    {
        printf("Context CSP acquired. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (GetLastError() == NTE_BAD_KEYSET)
        {
            printf("A Usable private key was not found \n");
            printf("in the default key container. Either a \n");
            printf("private key must be generated in that container \n");
            printf("or CryptAquireCertificatePrivateKey can be used \n");
            printf("to gain access to the needed private key.");
        }
        MyHandleError("CryptAcquireContext failed.");
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Open the My system certificate store.

    if (hStoreHandle = CertOpenStore(
        CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
        0,
        NULL,
        CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER,
        L"MY"))
    {
        printf("The MY system store is open. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("Error getting store handle.");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get the signer's certificate. This certificate must be in the
    // My store, and its private key must be available.

    if (pSignerCert = CertFindCertificateInStore(
        hStoreHandle,
        MY_ENCODING_TYPE,
        0,
        CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR,
        pswzCertSubject,
        NULL))
    {
        printf("Found certificate for %S.\n", pswzCertSubject);
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("Signer certificate not found.");
    }

    if (!CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(pSignerCert, CRYPT_ACQUIRE_CACHE_FLAG | CRYPT_ACQUIRE_SILENT_FLAG, NULL, &rsaCryptProv, &dwKeySpec, NULL))
    {
        MyHandleError("Cannot acquire private key.");
    }

   // does not seem to have any effect
    if (!CryptSetProvParam(rsaCryptProv, dwKeySpec == AT_KEYEXCHANGE ? PP_KEYEXCHANGE_PIN : PP_SIGNATURE_PIN, (LPBYTE)"123456", 0))
    {
        MyHandleError("Cannot set key pin.");
    }

   // causes all subsequent operations to fail
    if (!CertSetCertificateContextProperty(pSignerCert, CERT_KEY_PROV_HANDLE_PROP_ID, 0, (const void*)rsaCryptProv))
    {
        MyHandleError("Cannot set cert property.");
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize the algorithm identifier structure.

    HashAlgSize = sizeof(HashAlgorithm);
    memset(&HashAlgorithm, 0, HashAlgSize);    // initialize to zero
    HashAlgorithm.pszObjId = szOID_RSA_SHA256RSA;    // initialize the
                                               // necessary member
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize the CMSG_SIGNER_ENCODE_INFO structure.

    memset(&SignerEncodeInfo, 0, sizeof(CMSG_SIGNER_ENCODE_INFO));
    SignerEncodeInfo.cbSize = sizeof(CMSG_SIGNER_ENCODE_INFO);
    SignerEncodeInfo.pCertInfo = pSignerCert->pCertInfo;
    SignerEncodeInfo.hCryptProv = rsaCryptProv;
    SignerEncodeInfo.dwKeySpec = dwKeySpec;
    SignerEncodeInfo.HashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithm;
    SignerEncodeInfo.pvHashAuxInfo = NULL;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Create an array of one.
    // Note: The current program is set up for only a single signer.

    SignerEncodeInfoArray[0] = SignerEncodeInfo;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize the CMSG_SIGNED_ENCODE_INFO structure.

    SignerCertBlob.cbData = pSignerCert->cbCertEncoded;
    SignerCertBlob.pbData = pSignerCert->pbCertEncoded;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize the array of one CertBlob.

    SignerCertBlobArray[0] = SignerCertBlob;
    memset(&SignedMsgEncodeInfo, 0, sizeof(CMSG_SIGNED_ENCODE_INFO));
    SignedMsgEncodeInfo.cbSize = sizeof(CMSG_SIGNED_ENCODE_INFO);
    SignedMsgEncodeInfo.cSigners = 1;
    SignedMsgEncodeInfo.rgSigners = SignerEncodeInfoArray;
    SignedMsgEncodeInfo.cCertEncoded = 1;
    SignedMsgEncodeInfo.rgCertEncoded = SignerCertBlobArray;
    SignedMsgEncodeInfo.rgCrlEncoded = NULL;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get the size of the encoded, signed message BLOB.

    if (cbSignedBlob = CryptMsgCalculateEncodedLength(
        MY_ENCODING_TYPE,       // message encoding type
        0,                      // flags
        CMSG_SIGNED,            // message type
        &SignedMsgEncodeInfo,   // pointer to structure
        NULL,                   // inner content OID
        cbContent))             // size of content
    {
        printf("%d, the length of data calculated. \n", cbSignedBlob);
    }
    else
    {
        if (GetLastError() == NTE_BAD_KEYSET)
        {
            printf("A Usable private key was not found \n");
            printf("in the default key container. Either a \n");
            printf("private key must be generated in that container \n");
            printf("or CryptAquireCertificatePRivateKey can be used \n");
            printf("to gain access to the needed private key.");
        }
        MyHandleError("Getting cbSignedBlob length failed.");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Allocate memory for the encoded BLOB.

    if (pbSignedBlob = (BYTE*)malloc(cbSignedBlob))
    {
        printf("Memory has been allocated for the signed message. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("Memory allocation failed.");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Open a message to encode.

    if (hMsg = CryptMsgOpenToEncode(
        MY_ENCODING_TYPE,        // encoding type
        0,                       // flags
        CMSG_SIGNED,             // message type
        &SignedMsgEncodeInfo,    // pointer to structure
        NULL,                    // inner content OID
        NULL))                   // stream information (not used)
    {
        printf("The message to be encoded has been opened. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("OpenToEncode failed.");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Update the message with the data.

    if (CryptMsgUpdate(
        hMsg,         // handle to the message
        pbContent,    // pointer to the content
        cbContent,    // size of the content
        TRUE))        // last call
    {
        printf("Content has been added to the encoded message. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("MsgUpdate failed.");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get the resulting message.

    if (CryptMsgGetParam(
        hMsg,                      // handle to the message
        CMSG_CONTENT_PARAM,        // parameter type
        0,                         // index
        pbSignedBlob,              // pointer to the BLOB
        &cbSignedBlob))            // size of the BLOB
    {
        printf("Message encoded successfully. \n");
        FILE* fp = fopen("signed.p7m", "wb");
        fwrite(pbSignedBlob, cbSignedBlob, 1, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("MsgGetParam failed.");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // pbSignedBlob now points to the encoded, signed content.

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get a pointer to the recipient certificate.
    // For this program, the recipient's certificate must also be in the
    // My store. At this point, only the recipient's public key is needed.
    // To open the enveloped message, however, the recipient's
    // private key must also be available.

    if (pRecipCert = CertFindCertificateInStore(
        hStoreHandle,
        MY_ENCODING_TYPE,            // use X509_ASN_ENCODING
        0,                           // no dwFlags needed
        CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR,       // find a certificate with a
                                     // subject that matches the
                                     // string in the next parameter
        pswzRecipientName,           // the Unicode string to be found
                                     // in a certificate's subject
        NULL))                       // NULL for the first call to the
                                     // function
                                     // in all subsequent
                                     // calls, it is the last pointer
                                     // returned by the function
    {
        printf("Certificate for %S found. \n", pswzRecipientName);
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("Could not find the countersigner's "
            "certificate.");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize the first element of the array of CERT_INFOs.
    // In this example, there is only a single recipient.

    RecipCertArray[0] = pRecipCert->pCertInfo;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize the symmetric-encryption algorithm identifier
    // structure.

    ContentEncryptAlgSize = sizeof(ContentEncryptAlgorithm);
    memset(&ContentEncryptAlgorithm,
        0,
        ContentEncryptAlgSize);               // initialize to zero

 //-------------------------------------------------------------------
 // Initialize the necessary members. This particular OID does not
 // need any parameters. Some OIDs, however, will require that
 // the other members be initialized.

    ContentEncryptAlgorithm.pszObjId = szOID_RSA_DES_EDE3_CBC;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize the CMSG_ENVELOPED_ENCODE_INFO structure.

    memset(&EnvelopedEncodeInfo,
        0,
        sizeof(CMSG_ENVELOPED_ENCODE_INFO));
    EnvelopedEncodeInfo.cbSize = sizeof(CMSG_ENVELOPED_ENCODE_INFO);
    EnvelopedEncodeInfo.hCryptProv = hCryptProv;
    EnvelopedEncodeInfo.ContentEncryptionAlgorithm =
        ContentEncryptAlgorithm;
    EnvelopedEncodeInfo.pvEncryptionAuxInfo = NULL;
    EnvelopedEncodeInfo.cRecipients = 1;
    EnvelopedEncodeInfo.rgpRecipients = RecipCertArray;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get the size of the encoded message BLOB.

    if (cbEncodedBlob = CryptMsgCalculateEncodedLength(
        MY_ENCODING_TYPE,        // message encoding type
        0,                       // flags
        CMSG_ENVELOPED,          // message type
        &EnvelopedEncodeInfo,    // pointer to structure
        NULL,    // inner content OID
        cbSignedBlob))           // size of content
    {
        printf("Length of the encoded BLOB will be %d.\n", cbEncodedBlob);
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("Getting enveloped cbEncodedBlob length failed.");
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Allocate memory for the encoded BLOB.

    if (pbEncodedBlob = (BYTE*)malloc(cbEncodedBlob))
    {
        printf("Memory has been allocated for the BLOB. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("Enveloped malloc operation failed.");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Open a message to encode.

    if (hMsg = CryptMsgOpenToEncode(
        MY_ENCODING_TYPE,        // encoding type
        0,                       // flags
        CMSG_ENVELOPED,          // message type
        &EnvelopedEncodeInfo,    // pointer to structure
        NULL,    // inner content OID
        NULL))                   // stream information (not used)
    {
        printf("The message to encode is open. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("Enveloped OpenToEncode failed.");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Update the message with the data.

    if (CryptMsgUpdate(
        hMsg,              // handle to the message
        pbSignedBlob,      // pointer to the signed data BLOB
        cbSignedBlob,      // size of the data BLOB
        TRUE))             // last call
    {
        printf("The signed BLOB has been added to the message. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("Enveloped MsgUpdate failed.");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get the resulting message.

    if (CryptMsgGetParam(
        hMsg,                  // handle to the message
        CMSG_CONTENT_PARAM,    // parameter type
        0,                     // index
        pbEncodedBlob,         // pointer to the enveloped,
                               // signed data BLOB
        &cbEncodedBlob))       // size of the BLOB
    {
        printf("Enveloped message encoded successfully. \n");
        FILE* fp = fopen("encoded.p7m", "wb");
        fwrite(pbEncodedBlob, cbEncodedBlob, 1, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("Enveloped MsgGetParam failed.");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Clean up.

    CertFreeCertificateContext(pRecipCert);
    if (CertCloseStore(
        hStoreHandle,
        CERT_CLOSE_STORE_CHECK_FLAG))
    {
        printf("The certificate store closed without a certificate "
            "left open. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The store closed but a certificate was still open. \n");
    }
    if (hMsg)
        CryptMsgClose(hMsg);
    if (hCryptProv)
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
} // end main

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// This example uses the function MyHandleError, a simple error
// handling function to print an error message and exit
// the program.
// For most applications, replace this function with one
// that does more extensive error reporting.

void MyHandleError(char* s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "An error occurred in running the program. \n");
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error number %x.\n", GetLastError());
    fprintf(stderr, "Program terminating. \n");
    exit(1);
} // end MyHandleError
```

Comment: I can remember my colleagues having part of Windows replaced to do this, if that's *any* help.... Yes, that requires code signing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer and posting it here in case anyone needs it. The trick is to use CNG API instead of legacy crypto API:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wincrypt.h>

#define MY_ENCODING_TYPE  (PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING)

void MyHandleError(const char* s);

int main()
{
    BYTE* pbContent = (BYTE*)"Security is our only business.";
    DWORD cbContent = strlen((char*)pbContent) + 1;

    LPCWSTR pswzRecipientName = L"recipient";
    LPCWSTR pswzCertSubject = L"signer";

    HCERTSTORE hStoreHandle = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, NULL, CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER, L"my");

    if (hStoreHandle != NULL)
    {
        printf("The MY system store is open. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("Error getting store handle.");
    }

    PCCERT_CONTEXT pSignerCert = CertFindCertificateInStore(hStoreHandle, MY_ENCODING_TYPE, 0, CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR, pswzCertSubject, NULL);

    if (pSignerCert != NULL)
    {
        printf("Found certificate for %S.\n", pswzCertSubject);
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("Signer certificate not found.");
    }

    PCCERT_CONTEXT pRecipCert = CertFindCertificateInStore(hStoreHandle, MY_ENCODING_TYPE, 0, CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR, pswzRecipientName, NULL);

    if (pRecipCert != NULL)
    {
        printf("Certificate for %S found. \n", pswzRecipientName);
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("Could not find the countersigner's "
            "certificate.");
    }

    NCRYPT_HANDLE rsaKey;
    DWORD dwKeySpec = 0;
    if (!CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(pSignerCert, CRYPT_ACQUIRE_CACHE_FLAG | CRYPT_ACQUIRE_ONLY_NCRYPT_KEY_FLAG, NULL, &rsaKey, &dwKeySpec, NULL))
    {
        MyHandleError("Cannot acquire private key.");
    }

    if (NCryptSetProperty(rsaKey, NCRYPT_PIN_PROPERTY, (BYTE*)L"123456", 6, 0) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        MyHandleError("NCryptSetProperty failed.");
    }

    CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER HashAlgorithm;
    memset(&HashAlgorithm, 0, sizeof(HashAlgorithm));
    HashAlgorithm.pszObjId = szOID_RSA_SHA256RSA;

    CRYPT_SIGN_MESSAGE_PARA SignParam;
    memset(&SignParam, 0, sizeof(SignParam));
    SignParam.cbSize = sizeof(SignParam);
    SignParam.dwMsgEncodingType = MY_ENCODING_TYPE;
    SignParam.pSigningCert = pSignerCert;
    SignParam.cMsgCert = 1;
    SignParam.rgpMsgCert = &pSignerCert;
    SignParam.HashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithm;
    SignParam.dwFlags = CRYPT_MESSAGE_SILENT_KEYSET_FLAG;

    CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER CryptAlg;
    memset(&CryptAlg, 0, sizeof(CryptAlg));
    CryptAlg.pszObjId = szOID_RSA_DES_EDE3_CBC;

    CRYPT_ENCRYPT_MESSAGE_PARA EncryptParam;
    memset(&EncryptParam, 0, sizeof(EncryptParam));
    EncryptParam.cbSize = sizeof(EncryptParam);
    EncryptParam.dwMsgEncodingType = MY_ENCODING_TYPE;
    EncryptParam.ContentEncryptionAlgorithm = CryptAlg;

    DWORD cbEncodedBlob = 0;
    if (!CryptSignAndEncryptMessage(&SignParam, &EncryptParam, 1, &pRecipCert, pbContent, cbContent, NULL, &cbEncodedBlob))
    {
        MyHandleError("CryptSignAndEncrypteMessage failed.");
    }

    BYTE* pbEncodedBlob = (BYTE*)malloc(cbEncodedBlob);
    if (!CryptSignAndEncryptMessage(&SignParam, &EncryptParam, 1, &pRecipCert, pbContent, cbContent, pbEncodedBlob, &cbEncodedBlob))
    {
        MyHandleError("CryptSignAndEncrypteMessage failed.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Message signed and encrypted successfully. \n");
        FILE* fp = fopen("signed-encrypted.p7m", "wb");
        fwrite(pbEncodedBlob, cbEncodedBlob, 1, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    free(pbEncodedBlob);

    CertFreeCertificateContext(pSignerCert);
    CertFreeCertificateContext(pRecipCert);

    CertCloseStore(hStoreHandle, CERT_CLOSE_STORE_CHECK_FLAG);

    return 0;
}

void MyHandleError(const char* s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "An error occurred in running the program. \n");
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error number %x.\n", GetLastError());
    fprintf(stderr, "Program terminating. \n");
    exit(1);
}
```